# Limit of socket connection in Node JS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I use socket server with my love Node JS.

It is very perfect.

But i have a important question.

How many connection i can accept in node js?

Is there any limit for get connection?

Comment: This depends entirely upon your server configuration and your socket usage.  It is possible to configure a server to handle hundreds of thousands of simultaneous connections (even a million in some circumstances), but that takes careful configuration, a managed usage profile and the right hardware.  You also cluster with multiple processes on the same server and you can cluster with multiple servers.

Comment: check benchmarks on socket ok library, this has been answered too many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atleat 200K connection can accept in node js